# How to install latest Ruby on Gitlab config for Docker

Tags: ruby, docker, unix, gitlab

Here's how my config looks like:

```
deploy_hybrid:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apt update -qq
    - apt install ruby-full -qq
    - gem install cocoapods
    - pod repo update
```

However, it's always installing Ruby 2.1

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with
> caution in scripts. The following extra packages will be installed:
> libruby2.1 libtcl8.5 libtcltk-ruby libtk8.5 libxft2 libxss1 ri ruby
> ruby-dev   ruby2.1 ruby2.1-dev ruby2.1-doc ruby2.1-tcltk
> rubygems-integration